# Background noise Azure AMQP in Azure Bus metrics

Tags: azure, amqp, azureservicebus

See metrics from the Azure Service Bus below.  Want to identify the background noise in the number of requests | responses when there is low traffic.  Assuming that the oscillating request | response is latent to the amqp handshaking over a session.  Just can't understand what type of handshake it is?  Clients that are receiving from the Bus should have issued credit to the Bus (as a sender).  So there shouldn't be a need to poll.  Or is there?  Is there another background flow involved here?

Note, that the noise is coming from topics where there are about 4-5 subscriptions each.  Did a split by entity type.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Azure Service Bus client is using AMQP transport, it's 1.0 and also different from brokers such as RabbitMQ. With Rabbit the handshake would include credit from the client to the broker and broker would push. With Azure Service Bus the client is performing a long poll, by default configured to one minute. Therefore there will be always requests to the server.

Depending on the client you're using, there are different repositories to raise an issue to ask for to address it, though I'm skeptical it will be. For the .NET Standard client the repo is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues) and broker side issue tracker is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).